# Running ec2-describe-instances in EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to run ec2-describe-instances from a node in EC2 to see all my running instances.

I ssh into the instance and do:

> ec2-describe-instances

and get:

Required option '-O, --aws-access-key KEY' missing (-h for usage)

I'm not sure what this means.  I thought it might be the pem file I use to ssh in, so I scp'd it up and used this with the -O option but no dice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Greg , You need to pass security key and access key as parameters for that command , else you can set those as environmental variables also , you will get the those security and access keys from your account by accessing the link provided by @datasage in above answer .

Comment: Don't use the master account credentials. Create IAM user or role for it.

Answer (score 0):

The ec2 api requires security keys which are different from the ssh keys that you use to login the instance.

You should be able to get your keys here: https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?#security_credential